# Python: Closest Power of Two To Target

Tags: python, target

I am attempting to find the closest power of two that is greater than or equal to a target value. A for loop must be used to achieve this. However, I am unsure of what to put as the range value so that upon reaching the required value the exponent will stop increasing by i and instead exit the for loop. Thanks for your help.

```
target = int(input("Enter target number: "))
def power_of_two(target):

    x = 2
    change = 0
    power = 0
    for i in range():
        number = x ** change
        change = i
    if number >= target:
        power = number
    return power
p = power_of_two(target)
print("The closest power of 2 >= {0:d} is {1:d}." .format(target, p))
```

Comment: I think [break](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Would there be any other method to do this without a break? Or if the logic of the code were to be changed around? In any case thank you

Comment: @rabbit do you need to do it without a break for some reason?

Comment: I am attempting a python exercise question where the main focus is on a for loop and it should be able to naturally return the correct value without a break as it wouldn't be intended by the learning material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you have to use for:

```
def power_of_two(target):
    if target > 1:
        for i in range(1, int(target)):
            if (2 ** i >= target):
                return 2 ** i
    else:
        return 1
```

that is assuming you want the value to be greater than or equal to 2^0

Comment: Thank you this should meet the exercise requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I have corrected your code, so that it works. I think you learn best from your mistakes :)

```
target = int(input("Enter target number: "))

def power_of_two(target):
    x = 2
    change = 0
    power = 0
    for i in range(target+1):
                       # target is okay for this, function terminates anyway
                       # add one to avoid error if target=0
        number = x ** change
        change = i
        if number >= target:  # you had indentation errors here and following
            power = number    
            return power

p = power_of_two(target)
print("The closest power of 2 >= {0:d} is {1:d}." .format(target, p))
```

You could find a perfect value for the end of the range using logarithm with base 2, but then you wouldn't need the for loop anyway ;)

As a suggestion: maybe take a look at the binary representation of powers of 2. You could use a for loop with bitshifting for this.

**EDIT:** I had indentation errors myself, because of the weird formatting system here... maybe you haven't had these before :D

Comment: I see I shall save both of the codes for future reference. Thank you

Comment: Not to worry. I am already very grateful that you have shown me a way to improve my code. : D